# Pytorch: copy.deepcopy vs torch.tensor.contiguous()?

Tags: python, pytorch, torch

In python torch, it seems `copy.deepcopy` method is generally used to create deep-copies of torch tensors instead of creating *views* of existing tensors.
Meanwhile,
as far as I understood, the `torch.tensor.contiguous()` method turns a non-contiguous tensor into a contiguous tensor, or a *view* into a deeply copied tensor.

Then, do the two code lines below work equivalently if I want to deepcopy `src_tensor` into `dst_tensor`?

```
org_tensor = torch.rand(4)
src_tensor = org_tensor

dst_tensor = copy.deepcopy(src_tensor) # 1
dst_tensor = src_tensor.contiguous() # 2
```

If the two work equivalent, which method is better in deepcopying tensors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`torch.tensor.contiguous()` and `copy.deepcopy()` methods are different. Here's illustration:

```
>>> x = torch.arange(6).view(2, 3)
>>> x
tensor([[0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5]])
>>> x.stride()
(3, 1)
>>> x.is_contiguous()
True
>>> x = x.t()
>>> x.stride()
(1, 3)
>>> x.is_contiguous()
False
>>> y = x.contiguous()
>>> y.stride()
(2, 1)
>>> y.is_contiguous()
True
>>> z = copy.deepcopy(x)
>>> z.stride()
(1, 3)
>>> z.is_contiguous()
False
>>>
```

Here we can easily see that `.contiguous()` method created **contiguous** tensor from non-contiguous tensor while `deepcopy` method just copied the data without converting it to contiguous tensor.

One more thing `contiguous` creates **new** tensor **only** if old tensor is **non-contiguous** while `deepcopy` **always** creates **new** tensor.

```
>>> x = torch.arange(10).view(2, 5)
>>> x.is_contiguous()
True
>>> y = x.contiguous()
>>> z = copy.deepcopy(x)
>>> id(x)
2891710987432
>>> id(y)
2891710987432
>>> id(z)
2891710987720
```

#### contiguous()

Use this method to convert **non-contiguous** tensors to **contiguous** tensors.

#### deepcopy()

Use this to **copy** **nn.Module** i.e. mostly neural network objects **not tensors**.

#### clone()

Use this method to **copy tensors**.

Comment: OK. So, `tensor.clone()` is preferred if I'm to copy tensors and `tensor.contiguous()` was not created for deep-copying tensors. Thank you so much!

Comment: @hskim yes use clone() method to copy tensors